# If given a file containing all representable integers for an architecture, find missing integer(s)

Tags: algorithms

Suppose you have a file that contains all representable integers for an architecture (so, on a 64-bit machine, it would contain all integers representable in 64-bit).

However, not every integer is actually present, and the goal is to find which ones are missing. For only a single integer missing, it isn't too difficult. But what should be done if multiple integers are missing?

Comment: Please clarify how those integers are stored. The obvious way would make the file too large for anything I've heard of.

Comment: They're stored as normal integers, so a K-bit integer is just a size K set of bits in the file. Is there some other way to store the integers that makes the problem easier?

Comment: No algorithm for solving this is realistically possible for most actual machines.  Either the runtime would be so long you would effectively never see a result, or the memory usage would be larger than any machine reasonably available.

Comment: If we assume that we aren't bounded by the limitations of the machine, is there some algorithm beyond the naive solution to find the missing numbers?

Comment: @aricha1940 - probably not, to be honest, as even if you manage to compress each integer into a single bit, your storage space required for working on a 64-bit machine would approximately 1 library of congress, or about a 10th of a facebook.  The expense of even storing the input data for the algorithm you're asking about is astronomical, let alone the actual computing resources that would be required to run it.

Comment: That's boring. Watch here: https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Programming_Puzzles/Missing_number_in_billion_integers_.jsp or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398423/programming-pearls-finding-the-missing-integer-in-a-file-of-4-billion-integers

Comment: If this is supposed to be an interview question it's an awful one. If it's not an interview question, then dear god what in the world are you doing?

Comment: I'm not trying to do it for any real world purpose; I just ran across the question while browsing the web. It may be an interview question, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Probably storing the entire set of integers in memory is not possible.  For example a Uint type in C# requires 4 bytes of storage and you have around 4.2 billion of them, so you would need 17,179,869,180 bytes of storage or a little of 17.1 gig of memory just to store all the numbers.  If possible initialize a sorted list with all the possibilities and then process the file removing the entries from the list as they are found.  At the end, if all the numbers are there, the resultant list will contain zero entries.

Another approach would to use some sort of persistent storage like a database.  Load all 4.2 billion records (numbers) into the table.  One row for each number.  The primary key is the number.

Then start processing file using batch updates to delete the records of numbers in the file.  It would take a while but eventually all the billions of records in the file would be processed.

In this case, it should take very little memory to process entire file because the list is persisted.  The database may cache it anyway but from a program point of very we would be using very few resources.

If we are talking about longs, the requirements are even larger since upper values for longs (Int64) is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.  That's a tremendous amount of data to process and maintain.  Memory would not be an option and even using persistent storage would not be feasible due to the amount of possibilities.

You could split the entire list of numbers into partitions and potentially process the entire set over a farm of servers which each server keeping track of a set range of found numbers.  The could be possible if you had no resource constraints.

Comment: A better title for this question is:  How to process 146 Exabytes of information. 8 x2 x 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 gives the total spaces needed.   Times 2 to handle -negative ints.   Here's a good link to to sizing:  http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/9/11/how-big-is-a-petabyte-exabyte-zettabyte-or-a-yottabyte.html

Comment: You are using 1000 not 1024

Answer (score 0):

Well a simple solution is to sort them.

Which isn't that hard since their value tells you where to put them.  Might not be the fastest approach but it handles all cases provided we don't have or don't care about dupes.  Don't tell me we can't make a second list because we got this damn huge list somehow.  So screw it, we're making another one.  This time sorted. And we're doing it in O(n).

If space is a concern rather than time and simplicity then the second list can be made 64 times smaller than the first by expressing the existence of a number with one bit.  Found a 3? Go to the third bit and turn it on.  When finished all you have to do is find the zeros.  This basically compresses the sorted list.  It saves space but costs time.

But there are plenty of exploitable corner cases that may be worth filtering for before deciding what to do.

First I'd confirm if I could assume all numbers are unique.  If so I can tell exactly how many numbers are missing simply by counting the stored numbers and comparing that to the expected number of numbers.  Once I have that number I have a better idea how to adjust my approach and what corner cases to chase.  In big problems like this it's often a good idea to start with some quick investigation before starting a process you have to hope works over the weekend.

64 bits is an arbitrary number of bits.  We could have exactly the same discussion about 8 bits or 256 bits.  Some times it's worth knowing how hard a problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In memory I would create a 2 column list

low, high

first number goes in low

then one by one

- if number is low - 1 then it replaces low
- if number is low + 1 and high is empty then it goes in high 
  if number is high + 1 then is replaces high
- if high + 1 next low then merge
- if none of the above then start a new low in a proper sorted position

this will be like n(log n) 
and think space will be like log n

tested and it works
the size of the list climbs and then comes down

```
public void FindMissing()
{
    List<LowHigh> llist = new List<LowHigh>();
    Int32 num;
    int highCount = 0;
    LowHigh lh;
    LowHigh lhNext = new LowHigh(UInt16.MaxValue);
    LowHigh lhPrev = new LowHigh(0); 
    Random rand = new Random();
    List<Int32> testInts = new List<Int32>() { 1, 2, 4, 5, 3 };
    for (UInt32 i = 0; i < UInt16.MaxValue * 2; i++)
    //foreach (UInt16 i in testInts)
    {
        num = rand.Next(UInt16.MaxValue);
        //num = i;
        if(i % 1000 == 0)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(num);
        if (llist.Count == 0)
        {
            llist.Add(new LowHigh(num));
        }
        else
        {
            for (UInt16 j = 0; j < llist.Count; j++)
            {
                lh = llist[j];
                if (j < llist.Count - 1)
                    lhNext = llist[j + 1];
                if (j > 0)
                    lhPrev = llist[j - 1];
                if (j == 0 && num < lh.Low)
                {
                    llist.Insert(0, new LowHigh(num));
                    break;
                }
                else if (num >= lh.Low && num <= lh.High)
                    break;
                else if (num == lh.Low - 1)
                {
                    lh.Low = num;
                    if (j > 0)
                    {
                        if (lh.Low == lhPrev.High || lh.Low == lhPrev.High + 1)
                        {
                            lh.Low = lhPrev.Low;
                            llist.RemoveAt(j - 1);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else if (num == lh.High + 1)
                {
                    lh.High = num;
                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(lh.Low + " " + lh.High);
                    if (j < llist.Count - 1)
                    {
                        if (lh.High == lhNext.Low || lh.High == lhNext.Low - 1)
                        {
                            lh.High = lhNext.High;
                            llist.RemoveAt(j + 1);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else if (j < llist.Count - 1 && num > lh.High && num < lhNext.Low - 1)
                {
                    llist.Insert(j + 1, new LowHigh(num));
                    break;
                }
                else if (j == llist.Count - 1)
                {
                    llist.Add(new LowHigh(num));
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (llist.Count > highCount)
                highCount = llist.Count;
        }
        //foreach (LowHigh lhr in llist)
        //    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(lhr.Low + " " + lhr.High);
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(highCount);
    foreach (LowHigh lhr in llist)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(lhr.Low + " " + lhr.High);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
}
```